# Entity Framework exclude subclasses in query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a base class Nurse and an inherited class NurseDuplicate which I have mapped using TPC

```
   Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable(NURSES_TABLE);
            })
            .Map<NurseDuplicate>(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable(NURSEDUPLICATES_TABLE);
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
            });
```

Everything works fine when entering data. i.e. they both end up in their separate tables.
However when I query the database with

```
destinationDB.Nurses
```

I get both types returned, not just Nurses.

Is there any way to query the database so it only returns Nurses without NurseDuplicates?

Comment: You need a third type so that both Nurse and NurseDuplicate derive from a base NurseBase.

Comment: @Jasen Is there any way to do without NurseBase. Such as in the query?

Comment: Perhaps `db.Nurses.Where(n => !(n is DuplicateNurse))`

Comment: @Jasen Just tried that and it works perfectly.  Thanks!!